# Accessing istio-service-mesh from outside

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I have installed minikube and docker to run a kubernetes cluster on a virtual machine (Ubuntu 20.04). After that, I installed istio and deployed the sample book application. So far, so good. The problem I have is that i can't access the application from outside the virtual machine (my local computer). I've done everything like the istio tutorial said, but at the point where they say it is accessible now I simply can't reach it.

The istio-ingressgateway receives an IP-address, but it's the same as the cluster IP, therefore my local computer can't find it of course as it only knows the address of the node (VM). And the minikube IP is also different to the VM IP.

- istio-ingressgateway:

```
$ kubectl get svc -n istio-system
NAME                   TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP     PORT(S)                                                                      AGE
istio-egressgateway    ClusterIP      10.110.61.129   <none>          80/TCP,443/TCP,15443/TCP                                                     12m
istio-ingressgateway   LoadBalancer   10.106.72.253   10.106.72.253   15021:32690/TCP,80:32155/TCP,443:30156/TCP,31400:31976/TCP,15443:31412/TCP   12m
istiod                 ClusterIP      10.98.94.248    <none>          15010/TCP,15012/TCP,443/TCP,15014/TCP                                        13m
```

- minikube ip:

```
$ echo $(minikube ip)
192.168.49.2
```

- Node addresses:

```
$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens33: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0c:29:95:be:75 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.164.131/24 brd 192.168.164.255 scope global dynamic ens33
       valid_lft 1069sec preferred_lft 1069sec
    inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:fe95:be75/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    link/ether 02:42:e2:d8:bc:fc brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:e2ff:fed8:bcfc/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: br-1bb350499bef: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether 02:42:19:18:56:1b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.49.1/24 brd 192.168.49.255 scope global br-1bb350499bef
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:19ff:fe18:561b/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
12: vethec1def3@if11: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-1bb350499bef state UP group default
    link/ether 56:bd:8c:fe:4c:6b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 1
    inet6 fe80::54bd:8cff:fefe:4c6b/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

The address which should be working according to the istio documentation is http://192.168.49.2:32155/productpage (in my configuration), but this ends in a connection timeout.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you tried to access this URL from minikube machine? It should be working fine from minikube server and try with kubectl port-forward as well from local. Then please share the result.

Comment: Hi, could you please tell by outside you mean you don't have access from the host running `minikube` or the machine in your network that is trying to connect to your host? There are multiple options to deploy `Istio` in `minikube`. Could you please add exact steps you've followed to get to that point? Have you run other commands like `minikube tunnel`?